# How to auto generate invoice from sales order in suitescript 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitetalk

I've researching online on how to generate an invoice from a sales order through suitescript 2.0 but without any luck.

Could anyone shed a light on how to do this please.

Here's my situation:   Order is placed through API SOAP and I want to auto-generate an invoice once the order is placed on Netsuite.  Once the invoice is created, then email that invoice to the customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Suitescript 2.0 
[Record.transform](https://ursuscode.com/public/netsuitehelp/section_4267258715.html). You can trigger it on a User Event - After Submit script if you want it to happen in real-time.

Example:

```
//Add additional code 
...
var objRecord = record.transform({
    fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
    fromId: 107,
    toType: record.Type.INVOICE,
    isDynamic: true,
});
...
//Add additional code
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Adolfo Garza - I will test this one out.